# Date in iOS shows NaN

Tags: javascript, date, countdowntimer

I'm making this website with a countdown using javascript. When I deploy the website, everything is working fine in android and windows, but when I open the website on my iOS device the countdown turns into "NaN". Can anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

This is my countdown JavaScript code:

```
const newDate = new Date(serverTime).getTime();
const countdown = setInterval(() => {
    const date = new Date().getTime();
    const diff = newDate - date;

    const days = Math.floor(
        (diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * (365.25 / 12))) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    );
    document.querySelector(".days").innerHTML = days < 10 ? "0" + days : days;

    if (date >= newDate) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        document.querySelector(".days").innerHTML = "00";
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the format of `serverTime`?

> When parsing date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent), always make sure that the input conforms to the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ) — the parsing behavior with other formats is implementation-defined and may not work across all browsers.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

So if your `serverTime` string is not in this format, you’ll have unpredictable results.

If you need to parse a date from a different format, use a library such as `date-fns`.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD (2022-8-10). should i change this into YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ?

Comment: Yeah, I just updated my answer, you’ll want to change the format to that if possible, otherwise you can parse the date using a library such as `date-fns`

Comment: If the format is YYYY-MM-DD, it will be parsed as UTC. Adding "T00:00:00Z" will not make any difference to the outcome. However, "2022-8-10" is missing a leading zero on the month, so iOS is consistent with ECMA-262 in treating it as an invalid date.